# Как проверить наличие элемента в массиве?

Tags: java, массивы

Есть массив `arr`. Как проверить в нём **наличие** конкретного значения? Например, числа `1`. И можно ли сразу узнать его **индекс**? Если это важно, массив **двумерный**.
Мой код:

```
byte[][] arr = new byte[][]{{0, 0, 0}, 
                            {0, 1, 0},   // создал массив
                            {0, 0, 0}}

if (1 in arr){ // попытался проверить наличие
    ...
}
```

Comment: сделать два цикла очевидно надо

Comment: Вы о циклах for ?

Comment: ну хотя бы его, да

Comment: То есть в java нет встроенной автоматизации этого, как в python'е ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (int x = 0; x < arr.length; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < arr[x].length; y++) {
         if (arr[x][y] == 1) {
             // Соответственно X и Y - индексы элемента
             System.out.println(String.format("[%d][%d]", x, y));
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Я понял логику всего этого, но можно по-подробнее о строчке System.out.println(String.format("[%d][%d]", x, y));

Comment: Таким образом я просто вывожу индексы в консоль.
Что касается метода `String.format()`, то он просто помогает вставлять значения переменных прямо в строку, вместо всяких склеек типа `"["+x+"]"+"["+y+"]"`